# How can I write set these types properly using Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

How can I write this using typescript?

So I have a type Status which has three properties: name, actionName and style. I also have a constant statusTypes which has two properties of type Status.

This is what I did so far but it is not working. I am getting this error `[ts] Type '{ Active: any; Inactive: any; }' is not assignable to type 'Status[]'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'Active' does not exist in type 'Status[]'`

```
export interface Status {
  name: string;
  actionName: string;
  style: string;
}

export const statusTypes: Status[] = {
  Active : {
    name: "Active",
    actionName: "Deactivate",
    style: "success"
  },
  Inactive : {
    name: "Inactive",
    actionName: "Activate",
    style: "warning"
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

## The Problem

You are attempting to assign an object to a `Status` array.

## Solutions

Below is a list of some of the options you have. It is up to you to decide what works best in your design:

### Option 1: Array

```
export const statusTypes: Status[] = [{
    name: "Active",
    actionName: "Deactivate",
    style: "success"
  }, {
    name: "Inactive",
    actionName: "Activate",
    style: "warning"
  }
];
```

### Option 2: Index Signature

```
export const statusTypes: {[key: string]: Status} = {
  active: {
    name: "Active",
    actionName: "Deactivate",
    style: "success"
  }, 
  inactive: {
    name: "Inactive",
    actionName: "Activate",
    style: "warning"
  }
};
```

### Option 3: Interface

```
interface StatusTypes {
  active: Status;
  inactive: Status;
}

export const statusTypes: StatusTypes = {
  active: {
    name: "Active",
    actionName: "Deactivate",
    style: "success"
  }, 
  inactive: {
    name: "Inactive",
    actionName: "Activate",
    style: "warning"
  }
};
```

Comment: Problem with the index approach is that you will have to use`[]` to access proepries and more can be added since the indexer allows it.

Comment: Totally agree. If he wants to enforce that there are only the two properties, then an interface may be better.

Comment: I have edited my answer to add the option of using an interface, which eliminates the shortcoming of the index signature.

Answer (score 2):

Items in an array can't have names.

You can either create a simple array.

```
export const statusTypes: Status[] = [
    {
        name: "Active",
        actionName: "Deactivate",
        style: "success"
    },
    {
        name: "Inactive",
        actionName: "Activate",
        style: "warning"
    }
];
```

Or create an object and let the compiler infer the type for it :

```
export const statusTypes = {
    Active: {
        name: "Active",
        actionName: "Deactivate",
        style: "success"
    },
    Inactive: {
        name: "Inactive",
        actionName: "Activate",
        style: "warning"
    }
};
```

Or if you want to ensure the correct type for the properties you can define a helper function:

```
function defineStatuses<T extends { [name: string]: Status }>(o: T) {
    return o
}

export const statusTypes = defineStatuses({
    Active: {
        name: "Active",
        actionName: "Deactivate",
        style: "success"
    },
    Inactive: {
        name: "Inactive",
        actionName: "Activate",
        style: "warning"
    }
});
```

This last approach is the one I would recommend, you have full type safety as the compiler will warn you if you forget or add properties of `Status`, no extra interfaces to maintain and you can use defined properties (such as `Active`/`Inactive`) instead of `[string]`

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, the problem is that it's an array:

If that's the schema you want, you should achieve it like this:

```
interface StatusTypes {
 Active: Status;
 Inactive: Status
}

export interface Status {
  name: string;
  actionName: string;
  style: string;
}

export const statusTypes: StatusTypes = {
  Active : {
    name: "Active",
    actionName: "Deactivate",
    style: "success"
  },
  Inactive : {
    name: "Inactive",
    actionName: "Activate",
    style: "warning"
  }
};
```

Check it out at the [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%2F%2FAs%20others%20have%20mentioned%2C%20the%20problem%20is%20that%20it's%20an%20array%3A%2F%2F%20If%20that's%20the%20schema%20you%20want%2C%20you%20should%20achieve%20it%20like%20this%3A%20%20%20%20interface%20StatusTypes%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20Active%3A%20Status%3B%20%20%20%20%20Inactive%3A%20Status%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20export%20interface%20Status%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20actionName%3A%20string%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20style%3A%20string%3B%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20export%20const%20statusTypes%3A%20StatusTypes%20%3D%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20Active%20%3A%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%22Active%22%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20actionName%3A%20%22Deactivate%22%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20style%3A%20%22success%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20Inactive%20%3A%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%22Inactive%22%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20actionName%3A%20%22Activate%22%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20style%3A%20%22warning%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%7D%3B)

Whenever you want to have objects with keys, the correct way is to create interfaces, and each interface should have a property, which will be the object's key.

In English:

By assigning an object the interface `StatusTypes`, you are telling it that it's an object with `Active`, and `Inactive` keys whose shape conform to the `Status` interface. If you want to add another key to the `const statusTypes` you'd add it to the `StatusTypes` interface. If there is one key that you don't want it to be specified, append the "?" at the end of the property:

```
interface StatusTypes {
 Active: Status;
 Inactive: Status
 // This won't be required.
 optional?: Status
}
```

Comment: While you can define a dedicated type, that will mean having to maintain both the object and the type, I would avoid it if possible, let the compiler infer as much as possible ;-)

Answer (score 1):

After playing around a bit I figured out what I needed:

```
export interface Status {
  name: string;
  actionName: string;
  style: string;
}

export const statusTypes = {
  Active : <Status> {
    name: "Active",
    actionName: "Deactivate",
    style: "success"
  },
  Inactive : <Status> {
    name: "Inactive",
    actionName: "Activate",
    style: "warning"
  }
};
```

Comment: Yes, this also works. You can also define an interface that encapsulates what you are looking for, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/49326169/1057052

Comment: Type assertions are best used sparkingly,  They will let you add properties or forget properties. I would try to avoithem

Comment: While this works, I would not recommend this approach. If you want to ensure that all properties in `statusTypes` are of type `Status`, then there is nothing enforcing that. Also, asserting the properties to type `Status` doesn't ensure that those properties are actually of that type. See the map approach in my answer as an alternative.